# understanding jquery .on() method third parameter and var self = this

Tags: javascript, jquery

I see somewhere following jquery script, I want understand this script.
I am confuse regarding following code, first why create `var self` why not use keyword `this` on here  `$( '.some-class' ).on( 'click', 'a#some-link', self, this.bar.create );`

Second why use third parameter `self` when  this code also working fine:

`$( '.some-class' ).on( 'click', 'a#some-link', this.bar.create );`

Look the example code :

```
    ;(function($) {
            'use strict';

            var Foo = {

                initialize: function() {
                    var self = this;

                    $( '.some-class' ).on( 'click', 'a#some-link', self, this.bar.create );
                },
                bar: {
                       create: function(e) {

                      }
               }
            };

            $(function() {
                    Foo.initialize();
            });

     })(jQuery);
```

Comment: self/this in this case does not matter....

Comment: because someone didn't know what they were doing. `self` very well could h ave just been `this`, or it could have been omitted and the same problem solved with either an arrow function or .bind. Further enforcement of the initial statement is the selector used.

Answer (score 2):

So the on arguments are:

```
.on( events, selector, data, handler )
```

So in the `event.data`, the reference to the object is there.

When you leave off the self, that means event.data will not have that object. So if the code needed that reference for some reason, it would not be there.

```
$(document.body).on("click", "div", {pickle: "yes"}, function (event) {
  console.log(event.data); //{pickle: "yes"}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You usually need a context when triggering member function upon events.

For example consider this slightly modified version of your code:

```
// Your object
var Foo = { 
    initialize: function() {
        // VERSION 1:
        window.addEventListener("customEvent", this.bar.create);
        // VERSION 2:
        window.addEventListener("customEvent", this.bar.create.bind(this));
    }, 
    bar: {
        create: function() {
            console.log(this);
        }
    }
};
```

Now you can call explicitly your function like so:

```
Foo.bar.create();
// >> log your Foo object
```

Or trigger it with events

```
Foo.initialize();

// Send your event
var e = new Event("customEvent");
window.dispatchEvent(e);
// VERSION 1 will output window object
// VERSION 2 will output your Foo object
```

It's because in version 1, when your function is triggered it has no memory of its context when you attached the event (which is intended behavior). `this` will indeed be bound to the default object (`window`).

In version 2 I explicitly bind the function to its context so `this` will be bound to the Foo object.

---

Now about jQuery.on:

This 3rd argument is only meant to be the `.data` attribute of the event. Which mean whoever coded this wanted a reference to the Foo object.
if you `.bind(this)` the function you should be able to avoid passing it as argument.

Like so:

```
...
initialize: function() {
    $( '.some-class' ).on( 'click', 'a#some-link', this.bar.create.bind(this) );
},
...
```

Comment: nice explained!!